# Integration of cosec (2x) method

Tags: calculus

How to integrate $\csc (2x)$ by using substitution $t=\tan x$ ? I know a different way to solve it. But the book mentioned must be using substitution of tan x

Comment: $$cosec(2x) = \frac{1+tan^{2}x}{2tan(x)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$cosec(2x) = \frac{1}{sin(2x)} = \frac{1}{2sin(x)cos(x)} = \frac{cosx}{2sin(x)cos^{2}x} = \frac{sec^{2}x}{2\frac{sinx}{cosx}} = \frac{1+tan^2x}{2tanx}$

$$\int cosec(2x) dx = \int \frac{1+tan^2x}{2tan(x)} dx$$
Now put $t = tan(x) \implies dt = (sec^2x)dx = (1+tan^2x)dx = (1+t^2)dx$
Hence the integral becomes
$$\int \frac{1+t^2}{2t} \times \frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$

Can you complete the solution?

Comment: I got my answer as $1/2\ln (sin x)-1/2 \ln (cos x)$

Comment: But the answer given is $\frac{1}{2} ln (\csc (2x) -\cot (2x) )$

Comment: $ln(sinx) - ln(cosx) = ln(tanx)$ and $ln(csc(2x) - cot(2x)) = ln(\frac{1-cos2x}{sin2x}) = ln(\frac{2sin^{2}x}{2sin(x)cos(x)}) = ln(tan(x))$ Here the logarithmic property of $ln(a) - ln(b) = ln(\frac{a}{b})$ is used.

Comment: by the way. How to change $\csc 2x$ to $\frac{1+\tan^2 x}{2 \tan x}$

Comment: $cosec(2x) = \frac{1}{sin(2x)} = \frac{1}{2sin(x)cos(x)} = \frac{cosx}{2sin(x)cos^{2}x} = \frac{sec^{2}x}{2\frac{sinx}{cosx}} = \frac{1+tan^2x}{2tanx}$. Although I'd like to mention that the identity $sin(2x) = \frac{2tan(x)}{1+tan^2x}$ is worth memorizing.